# Type any Protocol cannot conform to Protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift5.7

I am facing an issue when trying to initialize a view in SwiftUI. Let me explain:

I have a view called ExternalView, this view has a constraint with a protocol called ToggleableProtocol, then, this view internally consumes a view called InternalView, which is a view that has a constraint to a Hashable protocol.

The error occurs when I try to create an instance of ExternalView and pass it an array of different structs that conform to the ToggleableItem protocol. The error says `Type 'any TogleableItem' cannot conform to 'TogleableItem'`

**TogleableItem**

```
public protocol TogleableItem: Hashable {
    var text: String { get }
    var isSelected: Bool { get set }
}
```

**Structs conforming to the TogleableItem**

```
struct FirstObject: TogleableItem {
    var text = "FirstItem"
    var isSelected = false
}

struct SecondObject: TogleableItem {
    var text = "SecondItem"
    var isSelected = false
}
```

**ContentView**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items: [any TogleableItem] = [
        FirstObject(),
        SecondObject()
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ExternalView(
            items: items
        ) { isSelected, index, _ in
            items[index].isSelected = isSelected
        }
    }
}
```

**ExternalView**

```
public struct ExternalView<T: TogleableItem>: View {
    private let items: [T]
    private let onItemTap: (Bool, Int, T) -> Void
    
    public init(
        items: [T],
        onItemTap: @escaping (Bool, Int, T) -> Void
    ) {
        self.items = items
        self.onItemTap = onItemTap
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        InternalView(
            items: items
        ) { index, element in
            Text(element.text)
                .foregroundColor(element.isSelected ? .red : .blue)
        }
    }
}
```

**InternalView**

```
struct InternalView<Element: Hashable, Content: View>: View {
    private let items: [Element]
    private let content: (Int, Element) -> Content
    
    init(
        items: [Element],
        content: @escaping (Int, Element) -> Content
    ) {
        self.items = items
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyHStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                content(index, items[index])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Thanks!!

I have tried changing the items parameter, inside the ExternalView to something like [any TogleableItem] but in the end it causes a similar error when consuming the InternalView

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that you define for instance `ExternalView` as  generic

```
ExternalView<T: TogleableItem>
```

then you say that `T` can be of a (read one) type that conforms to `TogleableItem` but you want to use the view for a mix of types that conforms to `TogleableItem`.

The solution as I see it is to *not* make the view types generics and instead use `TogleableItem` directly in the declarations (I have skipped a lot of code below for brevity)

```
public struct ExternalView: View {
    private let items: [any TogleableItem]
    private let onItemTap: (Bool, Int, any TogleableItem) -> Void
    ...
}

struct InternalView<Content: View>: View {
    private let items: [any TogleableItem]
    private let content: (Int, any TogleableItem) -> Content
    ...
}
```

Another way to solve it if InternalView should be able to use other types than those conforming to `TogleableItem` is to use the original solution but without `Element` conforming to `Hashable`

```
struct InternalView<Element, Content: View>: View {
    private let items: [Element]
    private let content: (Int, Element) -> Content
```

Comment: ...and you never call `onItemTap` anywhere in your Subviews code.

Comment: Yes, in fact, I am not calling onItemTap by mistake, since I adapted the code to the question. 

Thank you for the answer, however, as you can see in the post at the end I mentioned that I tried to do the same as you suggest, however, when trying to use internal view it throws an error saying that `Type 'any AlloyTextEditorTogleableAction' cannot conform to 'Hashable'`, so I would have to do the same in InternalView, however, when modifying internalView by a specific type, I would lose the scalability.

Comment: @MarkDev Are you saying that there should be no connection between ExternalView and InternalView so that the latter can be used for anything?